# Why should I overload a procedure? Why not add a procedurename?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, overloading

I've been overloading procedures for some time now, but recently asked myself what the actual advantage is in comparison to just adding a procedure with a slightly different name.

So basically, why should I use

```
Public Void DoSomething(Int FirstParam, String SecondParam)
Public Void DoSomething(String FirstParam, String SecondParam)
```

in stead of

```
Public Void DoSomething(Int FirstParam, String SecondParam)
Public Void DoSomething_V2(String FirstParam, String SecondParam)
```

If anything, a different procedure name actually might make it less confusing to see which procedure is called.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you don't `have to keep inventing the names`. To make the function more easy for others to recognise that it takes two strings, you will have to name the same function like DoSomething_TwoStrings.

If there is another function that takes one string and one int, you will have to name it like DoSomething_String_Int.

What if the order of the elements is to be changed and created into another function? If you choose to name your procedures as V2 and V1 etc., this will create another layer for users to remember. What does V2 take as input, and what about V1. `This all creates hundreds of more names than a user really has to remember if you don't use overloading`.

`Your program will also be clear due to having less vocabulary and smaller function names`. Once you know that IDE will clearly give you intellisense as to all the overloads and you can choose what you want, it is a piece of cake to use overload and is lot less cluttery.

Comment: So it's mainly that you don't have to think of new (relevant) names and there won't be any mistakes made in finding (a version of) the procedure. Fair points.

Comment: Absolutely.. It is a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Will you remember, when you're writing code a few months from now, that `DoSomething_V2` was the one that took two `String` parameters? `V2` is a spectacularly bad name.

Now if you're asking why not name them sensibly, then you get from `new File(...)` to `File.getInstanceFromParentFileAndChildString(File parent, String child)`, `File.getInstanceFromPathString(String path)`, `File.getInstanceFromParentAndChildStrings(String parent, String child)` and `File.getInstanceFromURI(URI uri)`.

This is the way Objective C went, and one of the biggest complaints from newcomers to the language is its amazing verbosity.

Comment: Agreed that V2 is probably bad, but I'm not really buying your point that I won't remember which procedure was the one with two strings. With code completion tools this shouldn't really a problem. And in comparison, if I have 5 overloaded procedures with the exact same name it makes it hard to see which version you're looking at.
Although I can see the problem with a lot of procedures with all slightly different names too. :)

Comment: It is not just for writing code, it is for readability too. Java philosophy is, if it makes a new `File`, we call it `new File(...)`. If it's connecting to a database, we'll call it `connect(...)`. This reads naturally enough, whatever the arguments, as long as the semantics is adequately described. ObjC on the other hand does not have overloading, and here people rely on IDE to remove the effort from typing very detailed method names such as `[addObserver:obs forKeyPath:path options:opts context:ctx]`. This makes ObjC very readable, but at the same time an IDE kind of indispensable.

Comment: Oh, realised I didn't answer the obvious question: what is stopping you from adopting the ObjC approach in Java? Two things: 1) Java does not intersperse words of the method name with parameters, making meaningful names for methods with many parameters unreadable (`addObserverForKeyPathWithOptionsAndContext(obs, path, opts, ctx)`), and 2) culture: all ObjC code uses the ObjC convention, and all Java code uses the Java convention. Writing against the convention decreases readability of your project for other developers.